# How to include values in a MySQL sum based on a conditional statement?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query which takes in the sum of columns 1-4, from the start of the current date, up to the current time.  My table has 5 columns, and I am trying to perform a conditional query based on a value in `column_5`.

I need to modify this query according to the following:

- If `column_5 > 0`, then I don't want to include the values from `column_1` in my sum, `Total`.
- But if `column_5=0`, then I do want to include the values from `column_1` in my sum `Total`.

At the moment, the values from `column_1` are included in my sum, regardless of whether `column_5` is greater than or equal to 0.

---

```
SELECT (column_1+column_2+column_3+column_4) at 'Total' 

FROM myDB.table_1

WHERE TS >= CURDATE() AND TS < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionals can be done by means of the [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) operator/expression:

Your query will work with:

```
SELECT 
    ts, 
    (CASE WHEN column_5 > 0 
     THEN
        0              /* We are ignoring column_1 */
     ELSE
        column_1       /* We are using its value */
     END) + column_2 + column_3 + column_4 AS total
FROM
    t
ORDER BY 
    ts ;
```

You can check it at http://rextester.com/IHM39024

The [`CASE` expression](http://modern-sql.com/feature/case) is standard SQL.

MySQL also offers an [`IF` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) that could be used in this case. In fact `IF(a,b,c) = CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE c END`.